# numeric keyboard does not work in debian

Tags: keyboard, debian-squeeze

I use a standard keyboard with debian 6.0.5. until now everything were fine. Now the numeric part of the keyboard does not work. numlock is on. if I press some random keys it does right click or opens the history in the browser. Can anyone help?

**[UPDATE]**

After some testing, I got that numbers on numeric part are moving mouse pointer.

4 --> move left

6 --> move right

8 --> move up

2 --> move down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine you're running Gnome (The default), which I don't use, but it sounds like you've enabled "*Mouse Keyboard Emulation*"

On my KDE system, it's toggle-able with **<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>**, I'll check here in moment for Gnome.

(Gnome users: [How to get numpad out of "mouse emulation" mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8664/how-to-get-numpad-out-of-mouse-emulation-mode).  Try **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>NUMLOCK</kbd>** (Setting may be found in *Universal Access*) )

---

Some Pictures... 'cause pictures are cool! (My sincerest apologies to the Gnome users, as I don't have a Gnome machine to take screenshots)

---

The two modules in **System Settings** to look at for mouse emulation settings and information: "*Shortcuts and Gestures*" and "Input Devices".

[image: System Settings Choices]

---

I've circled the important things to select, "*Global Keyboard Shortcuts*", "*KDE Component: KWin*" and the hotkey in question: "*Mouse Emulation: ALT-F12*"

[image: Keyboard HotKeys]

---

And in the "*Input Devices*" Module: Choose the mouse device, then examine the checkbox for "*Move pointer with keyboard*"

[image: Mouse Settings]

Hope this helps.